# text Start with "x"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the word "K" in my code to be the word in cell that start with "x" but i have tried it. And its not work.

Note : 
t1 = column F
t2 = Column G

such as instr(st, "+10") that mean if the word if column st has "+10" its mean true right but now i need the word in column H (st mean column H) has +10 and column F the word must start with "x"

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For b = 1 To a
If IsNumeric(Cells(b, "C").Value) Then
st = Cells(b, "G").Value

t1 = Cells(b, "F")
t2 = Cells(b, "H")

v1 = 1.72
v2 = 2.1
v3 = 1.9
v4 = 1.8
v5 = 2

If InStr(st, "+10") > 0 And t1 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "E") = v1
Cells(b, "J") = v2

ElseIf InStr(st, "-10") > 0 And t1 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "E") = v3
Cells(b, "J") = v3

ElseIf InStr(st, "-5") > 0 And t1 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "E") = v5
Cells(b, "J") = v4

ElseIf t1 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "E") = v4
Cells(b, "J") = v5

ElseIf InStr(st, "+10") > 0 And t2 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "J") = v1
Cells(b, "E") = v2

ElseIf InStr(st, "-10") > 0 And t2 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "J") = v3
Cells(b, "E") = v3

ElseIf InStr(st, "-5") > 0 And t2 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "J") = v5
Cells(b, "E") = v4

ElseIf t2 = "K" Then
Cells(b, "J") = v4
Cells(b, "E") = v5


ElseIf InStr(st, "-10") > 0 Then
Cells(b, "J") = v3
Cells(b, "E") = v3

Else
Cells(b, "E") = 0
Cells(b, "J") = 0

End If

End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwiRk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3df7.png)

Comment: Can  you expand on your question. Please take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also why is `t1` Set to column F but then you're comparing it to `K`? Same with `t2`?

Comment: I just want change t1 = "K" to the word in Column F that start in "x"

but i dont know the code

Comment: Can you include in your question how you're setting `t1` and `t2`

Comment: such as instr(st, "+10") that mean if the word if column st has "+10" its mean true right

but now i need the word in column H (st mean column H) has +10 and  column F the word must start with "x"

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NwiRk.png if it work its wiill look like this. But just now i change the text "K" to text start with "x" http://i.stack.imgur.com/r3df7.png like this picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you but... Are you looking for a way to test the first character of the column F? then:

```
If InStr(Cells(b, "H"), "-10") > 0 And left(Cells(b, "F"), 1) = "x" Then
```

Comment: Ok ^^ Next times try to abstract your question, could be easier for understand.

Comment: Sorry i'm bad in English skill